# Loop in Tip Calculator (Python)

Tags: python

So I'm making a tip calculator at the moment. The thing that I am stuck on is where they can input the total amount of the cost. If they input an integer I want it to break out of the loop but if they input something else than an integer, I want it to stay in the loop and tell them to enter an integer. Here is the code that I made for this portion. (Not all the code)

```
Integer = range(1,10000)




while True:
    while True:
        Cost = raw_input("What was the cost? ")
        Cost = int(Cost)
        if Cost in Integer:
            break
        else:
            pass
```

The spacing may not look correct but it is in the actual script. I still don't know how to paste the code on here without having to add 4 spaces to every line. Anyway, please let me know what you would do to complete the task I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cost = int(Cost)` will raise a ValueError if Cost is not a string for an Integer.

as such,

```
    while True:
        Cost = raw_input("What was the cost? ")
        try:
             Cost = int(Cost)
             break
        except ValueError:
             print("Please enter an Integer for the cost")
```

as you can see, break will only be executed if the ValueError is not raised.

You should not do this though. What you should do is test for isdigit before casting:

```
    while True:
        Cost = raw_input("What was the cost? ")
        if Cost.isdigit():
             Cost = int(Cost)
             break
        else:
             print("Please enter an Integer for the cost")
```

exceptions make control flow be unobvious and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: The outer loop is for the rest of the code. I did not put all the code in the example, just the loop I was having trouble with. Thank you for your answer I appreciate it.

Comment: "You should not do this though." Why not? This is perfectly valid Python code. As opposed to the other, it uses [EAFP instead of LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), which is the preferred way of doing things in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a String object to an int can raise a ValueError exception, however
since `raw_input()` returns a `str` object you can easily check if it's all digits with `isdigit()`. The full documentation of the `isdigit()` is [found here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

```
if cost.isdigit():
  cost = int(cost)
  break
else:
  cost = raw_input("What is the cost? ")
```

That was problem number 1.
Problem number 2 you're facing is `if Cost in Integer`.

This is not how that works, you're probably after `if isinstance(cost, int):` because you want to check if it's an integer after all (since you're converting it)

and lastly:

You should not use `while True`, while this is working for you you wont be able to break it since you haven't assigned `True` to a variable.

```
outer = True
inner = True

while outer:
  while inner:
    #your code here
    inner = False #now it will break automatically from the inner loop.
```

Comment: testing for isdigit is much prettier than my solution. didn't know about it. props to you.

Comment: If the amount is dollars and cents, `isdigit()` will be `False`: `'123.45'.isdigit() == False`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, this is true but I left it out for the OP as an exercise. Covering all corner cases is a pain.

Comment: You can easily cover it with `float(Decimal('123.45'))` :)